# How can I trigger form error handling in React / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am using Material-UI Google Autocomplete, https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#google-maps-place, to require users to fill out their address.

[image]

My main question is, how can I force this "Please fill out this field." popup to show up, even when the field is not blank. For example, if a user starts to type "Made up address 124" but does not select from the Google autofill drop down, I'm never able to set a place_id on the form. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {form} = this.state;
    if(!form.google_place_id){
      // Trigger "Please fill out this field." error handling and don't submit the form.      
    }
    this.props.onSubmit(form);
}
```

Comment: That’s native input behaviour when you use the required attribute. Not a library or JS

Comment: Can I force this to trigger, even when the attribute that is required is filled out?

Comment: If it is filled out it makes no sense to show that...

Comment: Well I want a custom error message to say "Please select an option from the dropdown". If they don't select anything, but instead just try to submit with what they've typed in, I want to show the error.

Comment: The validation message is coming from the default HTML5 input element. Take a look at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) for some more details

Comment: That message is not customisable afaik

Answer (score 0):

The popup bubble you see is built into Browser according to html5 specifications.

But to answer your question on how to determine if option is selected or not, you can either implement this feature yourself, or rely on Autocomplete Component API you are using.

https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

Here, I can see you can try `freeSolo` and `getOptionSelected` .
Setting freeSolo to false makes user input bound to the options.

Also look into `autoHighlight` and `autoSelect` as this may force an option to be selected.

If you want more control over rather your input is one of the options, then simply check it yourself.

```
const optionsObject = {   optionKey1: true, optionKey2: true }

useEffect(()=> {
    if(optionsObject[input]) {
     // input is one of the options
    } else {
  // input is not one of the options
  }
}, [input, optionsObject])

<Autocomplete 
    options={ Object.keys(optionsObject))
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. However my question is not how to determine if an option is selected or not. My question is, once I KNOW an option is not selected, how can I trigger the browser html5 bubble to popup and say "Please select an option from the drop down"?

Comment: As a suggestion you never want to rely on specific browser bubble since it is different on every browser and will be changed over different versions even on the same browser. What you want to do is create a custom bubble that shows up once you know an option is not selected using component state.